# Probability Generating Function Attempt

Tags: probability-theory, summation, generating-functions

I am trying to find the PGF for the following distribution:

$X_1$ has PMF: $\rho(x) = \frac{-p^x}{x\ln(1-p)},n\in \mathbb N$

**Attempt:**
\begin{align*}
\phi_{X}(s) &= E[s^x]\\
&=\sum^{\infty}_{x=1} s^x \frac{-p^x}{x\ln(1-p)}\\
&=\frac{1}{\ln(1-p)} \sum^{\infty}_{x=1} \frac{-(sp)^x}{x}\frac{\ln(1-sp)}{\ln(1-sp)}\\
&=\frac{\ln(1-sp)}{\ln(1-p)}, ~~~~~~~~~s<\frac{1}{p}
\end{align*}

Just found that this is a well known distribution called the log series distribution. My result is correct as verified by:

http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Log-SeriesDistribution.html

Answer (score 1):

Hint: you already did a very similar sum in showing that your distribution actually is a probability distribution.

Comment: is that what you meant ?